# How to host prisma application on cpanel?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, prisma

I build a express app with prisma, and upload to cpanel hosting, then run this command:
`npx prisma migrate dev`
`npx prisma migrate deploy`
`npx prisma generate`

and get this same error

```
Error: Unable to require(`/home/u1254216/nodevenv/node_apps/cpanel_prisma/16/lib/node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node`)
 /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /home/u1254216/nodevenv/node_apps/cpanel_prisma/16/lib/node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node)
```

my `schema.prisma` file:

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

prisma version:

```
"prisma": "^3.9.1"
"@prisma/client": "^3.9.1"
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting OS is centOS, You can't run prisma, Because it's need some libs (like GLIBC_2.18) that not install on centOs.

Comment: Hi, I got the "GLIBC_2.18 not found" before read this.
So, any solution to solve it?
or, if the hosting not using centOS?
which OS will run Prisma well in hosting?
tyvm

Comment: If your hosting uses at least ubuntu 18 it is done. `GLIBC_2.18` not install on any version of centOs